# Can I implement a line over bar chart instead of dot over bar chart?

Tags: highcharts, linechart

```js
mychart.addSeries
(
    { 
        type: 'line', name: '{!selectedTypevalue}', lineWidth: 0,  data: bdataYTD4, stack : 0, pointPlacement: 0, showInLegend: true, tickColor: '#FF0000',tickWidth: 3, marker: { symbol: 'line', fillColor: '#F58F00' }, states: { hover: { enabled: false }, }
    }
)
```

[I want a line over bar instead of the dot over bar in the second graph below. Need help to implement this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOAew.png)

I used the type = line attribute but it does not work.

[This is what I get when I increase the lineWidth.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcejd.png)

[Can I have lines like this instead of the dot?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRXsu.png)

Comment: Hi @Carine D'Mello, You are probably using two series in the second chart - bar and scatter. Changing the scatter series to a line seems to be enough. Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5ck4vdh6/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you for your response. Please find below the code. Any inputs would be helpful.

Comment: var mychart = Highcharts.chart("container1", {
  chart: {
    type: "bar",
    zoomType: "y",
  },
  xAxis: {
categories: bdataYTD3,
  },
    bar: {
dataLabels: {
enabled: true,
format: "{y}"
 },
zones: [{              value: 0,
color: '#EF412F'
          }]
    },
  },
  series: [
{
name: 'Quota rating',
data: bdataYTD5
    },
  ]
});
mychart.addSeries({ type: 'line', name: '{!selectedTypevalue}', lineWidth: 0,  
data: bdataYTD4, stack : 0, pointPlacement: 0, showInLegend: true, tickColor: '#FF0000',tickWidth: 3,
marker: { symbol: 'line', fillColor: '#F58F00' },});

Answer (score 0):

The line is not visible because there is the `lineWidth` option which is set to `0`. You need to increase the value, for example:

```
mychart.addSeries({
  lineWidth: 1,
  ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8sLvq1hu/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.lineWidth

Comment: I tried doing it but the dots remain, and they are joined by lines. Is there a way I can display a line in place of a dot? I have added an image of what we get on increasing the lineWidth in the question details.

Comment: I have also added an image of the line we want to display

Comment: Hi @Carine D'Mello, Thanks for the explanation! However, I am still not quite sure of the wanted result. Do you want to have additional bar series as lines? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3c0yq4hw/ or maybe only a different symbol for a scatter series? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yvz3s9ro/